# Keep Background Fixed but Let Photos Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, three.js

I'm working on my website [www.kdoan.com](http://kdoan.com/) and I can't seem to figure out how to make my Three JS background animation stay the same (fixed) while allowing my project sections scroll normally. They used to work just fine and you could scroll through the rest of the photos.

For example if you enter my site and on the left go to projects and then Hydration there's an image of one of my works but you can't scroll to see the rest. I can make it so you can but it ends up breaking the aesthetic and you see a white background. If anyone can help or guide me with this that'd be great. Thanks!

Comment: Okay I'll do that now

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to include all the html of the page (text and images) in a div, make it scrollable and make it fill the page.
So the code I'm suggesting is this:

```
<div style="width:100%; height:100vh; overflow-y:scroll;">
    Hydration is a series of 3d models I worked on with Yung Jake.
    The pieces consisted of distorted bottles that were refracted against
    different images and then printed onto metal canvases. ...
</div>
```

By the way, that's a wonderful background !!!

Please let me know if this was helpful.